# Gurubi python constraint using quicksum

Tags: python, gurobi

I have an optimization problem using Python and Gurobi. In my problem formulation there is the following constraint:

[image]

Here, w_it is a decision variable and G_it is a parameter expressed using a dictionary.
For example,

```py
Git = {( 't1', 1): 4, ( 't1', 2): 3, ....}
```

The right side of the constraint is the sum of G_i1, G_i2, ... G_it

```py
con3 = m.addConstrs(wit[i,t] <= gp.quicksum(Git[i,t]) for i in NC for t in time_shifts)
```

Comment: Please do not post images of code

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues:

1. I suggest you use variables w and G, not wit and Git.
2. The convention is for decision variables `w[i,t] >= 0`, so there is no need to write this constraint explicitly.
3. It looks like there is some confusion between t and tau. I'll try to make this clear.

What you need looks like this:

```
con3 = m.addConstrs(w[i,t] <= gp.quicksum(G[i,tau] for tau in range(1,t+1))
                                          for i in NC
                                          for t in time_shifts)
```

You may need to adjust the range depending on whether time_shifts counts from 0 or from 1.